# Can a Dataprep Flow be owned by a non personal Google Account or Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

Does a Flow need to be owned by a user with a Google Account? A flow broke because we disabled an employees account. We reenabled so its working again but would like to change the owner of the flow to a Service Account or a non-personal account. I'm finding that you need to login to Dataprep though, which makes me think it may need to be owned by a Google Account.

Please help! :)

Comment: You should ask your question at https://community.trifacta.com/ directly. I found a similar question https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00005ro9kJSAQ/how-can-i-change-the-owner-of-a-flowi-know-that-there-can-only-be-one-owner-so-i-want-to-transfer-my-flows-to-another-account-how-can-i-do-that but it just refers to the sharing feature